# Java while loop not repeating

Tags: java, loops, validation, while-loop

I am writing this code where the user puts the username and password then I validate the entries in a database. The problem with my code is that when the input is wrong it does not return and repeat the data input process from the while loop. My code is as below. If someone could help me fix it. Thank you in advance.

```
boolean b = true;
while (b == true) {
    System.out.println("enter username");
    String username = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("enter password");
    String password= scanner.next();
    boolean result = userDao.validate(username, password);

    if (result == false) {
        System.out.println("password email do not match");
        scanner.next();
    } else {
        System.out.println("success");
        b = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `scanner.next()` from the if statement?

Comment: What is the purpose of `scanner.next();` after `System.out.println("password email do not match");`?

Comment: If you're using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, you can figure this out by using the debugger. Let the code run and pause the debugger when it's stuck. If it's not stuck, you can also step through line by line to see what's going on.

Comment: hello!, Did you see wether in your userDao.validate() crash something? i mean, are you sure that result have a value from this method?, maybe don't get back result data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough "reputation points" to provide a comment.. but curious if you would be able to remove scanner.next() within your if statement if that would do the trick.

I tried it by setting the result to false and letting it run.

```
if (result == false) {
            System.out.println("password email do not match");
            //scanner.next();

        } else {
            System.out.println("success");
            b = false;
        }
```